# Aggregate jsonb object inside nested jsonb object array without expanding the array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation, jsonb

Let's say I have a city model that has a neighborhood model which contains jsonb[] field of families, which is an array containing jsonb objects, each object has a data object inside with count and income fields

| ID | data |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {"city": {"neighborhood": {"families": [{"name": "Miller","data": {"count": 3,"income": 1200}},{"name": "Bennet","data": {"count": 4,"income": 700}}]}}} |
| 456 | {"city": {"neighborhood": {"families": [{"name": "Olsen","data": {"count": 7,"income": 1100}},{"name": "Yang","data": {"count": 1,"income": 7000}}]}}} |

I want to aggregate the maximum count for each row, so the required output will be

| ID | count |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 4 |
| 456 | 7 |

I can achieve it with a subquery using jsonb_each to expand each family to a row and then aggregate the results, but I'm worried about the performance impact of this operation because each row may contains many families,
Do I have a way to do it without expanding the results?

Comment: You need to turn the single huge JSON value into multiple rows in order to be able to aggregate. There is no way around that. You could have stored it in a properly normalized way to begin with, then this would be a very simple query. Btw: `jsonb[]` hardly ever makes sense over a "plain" `jsonb` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    main.id, 
    max(main."count") as "count" 
from 
    (
        select 
            t1.id, 
            (jsonb_array_elements_text(t2.value::jsonb)::jsonb->'data'->'count')::integer as "count" 
        from table1 t1 
        join jsonb_each_text(t1."data"->'city'->'neighborhood') t2 on true 
    ) main 
group by main.id
```

Result of this query:

| id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | 7 |
| 123 | 4 |